# Ascoli Arzelà in Infinite dimension

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

In which book can I find the Ascoli Arzelà theorem for the space $C([0,T];H)$ where $H$ is a generic Hilbert space?

Comment: This [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.4883.pdf) in the ArXiv may be of interest to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the more general version of the Azelà-Ascoli theorem from Theorem XII.6.4 in Dugundji's book on topology.

Comment: thanks, but I don't solve my problem anyway, can you please check the question that I edited?

Comment: Please don't edit a question to ask something completely different after you received an answer already. Better post a new question.

Comment: yes sorry, I'll create a new post